# Login loop in Xubuntu 17.10 after upgrade from Xubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: upgrade, xubuntu, login, 17.10, lightdm

I have recently upgraded from Xubuntu 16.04 LTS to Xubuntu 17.10 (Yeah, I know it wasn't a good idea, but i did for testing purposes).

So now I have login loop problem. I have already googled for this problem. Reinstalling lightdm did not help me. Removing .Xautority file did not help either.

Has anyone had this situation? Any thoughts on how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem what I did was get the XDM so I went Ctrl+ALt+F2 and did:

```
sudo apt install XDM
sudo service LightDM stop
sudo service XDM start
```

Comment: Thanks! Probably not the nicest solution, but at least I could log in into XFCE ))).